# Is this a good practice to replace 'const std::string &' with 'std::string_view' or just 'std::string'?

Tags: c++, string, c++17, move-semantics, string-view

I preferred `const std::string &` always when I need to play with `std::string`s. But recently, I suddenly noticed that there's no need to use `const std::string &` at all. The `std::string_view` will do better for read-only strings, and just `std::string` with `move` will do better for otherwise(setting string fields, etc).

```cpp
// Read-only string example
bool foo(std::string_view bar) {
    return bar == "baz";
}
```

```cpp
// Non read-only string example
void MyClass::foo(std::string bar) {
    this->baz = std::move(bar);
}
```

In above two cases, `const std::string &` is not optimal!

So I decided to remove all `const std::string &`s and replace these with one of them. So my question is :

1. Will there any situation that `const std::string &` do better?
2. If no, will I still need `const std::string &`?

Thank you.

Comment: The view is also nicer when calling the function with a literal string as it doesn't need to construct a temporary `std::string` from it. Or is that what you meant by read only string?

Comment: @Shawn I mean, `read-only string` is strings that are not get modified in a function. Yes, it can be created from literals, or reference of an existing string instance maybe.

Comment: @AcrylicShrimp, `std::string` holds a zero-terminated string, so the value returned by `c_str()` method can be passed directly to one of functions (espacially when dealing with c-functions) that expects a zero-terminated c-string as an input argument. Conversely this can not be done using the `std::string_view` solely (you need to create a buffer that will hold a zero-terminated c-string in this case).

Comment: @RealFresh But every `std::string_view` created by `std::string`s and string literals will be null-terminated, right?

Comment: Not if it's a view of a substring.

Comment: What I still don't get (with `std::string_view`): For non-meta programming, where a function expects a `const std::string&` (and cannot be changed because it's third-party or just too much effort), a `std::string_view` has to be copied (and even explicitly) while a `std::string` would match perfectly. (New fancy features also have draw-backs if you are bound to a big, long-living code-base - my sad experience.) Or, did I overlook something?

Comment: For the setter case, user might misuse it and so creates extra copy (`std::string s = f(); foo(s)` instead of `foo(std::move(s));`). Expecting `std::string&&` would force user to do the copy explicitly.

Comment: I also want to know if we can remove all `const std::vector<T>& v` and replace these with c++20 `span<const T>`.